# wsadmin: How to inspect existing resource references?

Tags: websphere, mbeans, wsadmin

With `$AdminApp view <applicationName> -MapResRefToEJB` it is possible to list the resource references defined for a deployed EJB module. However, the result of that command  is plain text (that in addition may be localized). To extract that information one would have to parse this text, which is not very convenient. Is there a way to get the same information (i.e. the resources references of an application) in a structured form using $AdminConfig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`AppManagement` MBean](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/AppManagement.html) provides this data in a structured format (Vector of [`AppDeploymentTasks`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fmanagement%2Fapplication%2Fclient%2FAppDeploymentTask.html&resultof=%22appdeploymenttask%22)). To obtain this data using `wsadmin` scripting (`jython`):

```
import javax.management as mgmt
appName = sys.argv[0]
appMgmt = mgmt.ObjectName(AdminControl.completeObjectName("WebSphere:*,type=AppManagement"))
appInfo = AdminControl.invoke_jmx(appMgmt, "getApplicationInfo", [appName, java.util.Hashtable(), None], ["java.lang.String", "java.util.Hashtable", "java.lang.String"])
for task in appInfo :
    if (task.getName() == "MapResRefToEJB") :
        resRefs = task.getTaskData()
        # skip the first row since it contains the headers
        for i in range(1, len(resRefs)) :
            resRef = resRefs[i]
            print
            print "URI:", resRef[4]
            print "EJB:", resRef[3]
            print "Name:", resRef[5]
            print "Type:", resRef[6]
            print "JNDI:", resRef[8]
```